# How to insert some new rows of data into my heroku postgres database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Recently I uploaded my local database to Heroku by first resetting the database using the `Heroku pg:reset` command and then uploading my own database.

Now I want to insert(append) some rows(around 100) into a particular table in Heroku database from my local db without resetting the table and then uploading the table again. I am unable to find any resources or commands to do that.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django's `dumpdata` and `loaddata` to perform this. But, you need to cut the data to whatever size you want. I don't think it will provide you this feature out of the box. Make sure that your primary keys are not overlapping with the existing data. you can find a link [here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata).

Comment: Are there any commads to cut the data or to take data above a specific id. For e.g. If I want data from id 1534 and above how should I write the dump command

Comment: I don't think `dumpdata` can do that. Instead, you can dump all the data and write a python script to segregate the data.